# Pandas convertir número en formato Object a float

Tags: pandas, objeto, float, numberformat

He intentado resolver esto buscando en este foro y en otras webs pero no soy capaz. Soy novato con Python y Pandas y esto me está bloqueando todo mi trabajo.

He importado un excel y creado un df. Tengo una columna con este formato: `-000000500,00` que a pesar de ser números los importa como objeto. En el excel inicial tampoco se consideran números.

```
*MONTANT        object*
```

He conseguido llegar a transformarlo a esto: `-500,00` (no sé si vale para algo) pero sigue siendo objeto.

*FINAL MONTANT       object*

Necesito convertirlo a `float` para poder usar esa columna en una pivot y exportar la pivot en excel.

He probado varias opciones:

1)

```
df['FINAL MONTANT decimal']= pd.to_numeric(df['FINAL MONTANT'],errors = 'coerce')
```

*Resultado:

```
FINAL MONTANT decimal        **float64***
```

Pero me aparecen todos como `NaN`

2)

```
*df['FINAL MONTANT decimal']=df['FINAL MONTANT'].astype("float64")*

*ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-500,00'*
```

Muchas gracias de antemano y disculpad si hice algo mal en la publicación.

Un saludo.

---

Acabo de ver que si cambio la , por . en mi excel original sí me transforma a floating con la primera opción, voy a probar.

Comment: Buen día, por favor agrega algunas filas de tu `dataframe` como texto, no como imagen para que podamos ver el formato de la información.

Comment: Si estas utilizando `read_csv` o similar, hay un argumento que permite configurar el caracter tanto para el delimitador como para el decimal.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato creo que lo estoy apañando reemplazando las "," por "."   Investigaré por internet lo que dices, estoy usando read_excel, pero supongo que es igual. Muchas gracias por tus respuestas.